# iPad : Problem changing the background color of Grouped TableView in iOS SDK 4.2

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios-4.2

I am using iOS SDK 4.2.

In my iPad app, I am not able to change the background color of **Group Table View** even it does not set to clear color

If I try to change the table view style from **Grouped Table View** to **Plain Table View** and then try changing the background color then it changes.

But something seems to be wrong when I am using Grouped Table View

What could be wrong?

What should I do?

Plese Help and Suggest

Thanks.

Comment: what code are you using to try change it at the moment?

Comment: @mackross: I am changing it from inspector in the XIB itself

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to set the TableView background clear so I can display the cells over the top of my own background image. The fix below works in iOS4.2 on the simulator but not on the iPad device:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688007/uitableview-backgroundcolor-always-gray-on-ipad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this problem as well. Only on iPad. Only with a grouped Table.

You can fix this by creating a new view, coloring it and then setting that new view to the backgroundView of the tableView.

This works for static colors, but not Pattern Images(what I'm trying to do)

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you. This solved even my problem. :) Thanks

Comment: This is the correct solution if you are working with `UIAppearance`, which means that you do not define `UItableview`s background color in the viewcontroller but in a config file. setting `backgroundView` to nil doesnt help for this specific case

Answer (score 14):

Set `nil` to the tableview's backgroundView will solve the problem.

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

BackgroundView works only with ios 3.2 and later.

So check

```
if([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundView)]) 
     tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

For backward compatibility, otherwise app will crash.

Comment: Great! my only comment: Can use `self.tableView` instead of `tableView`.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problem in linking your outlet of table.
Setting the background color is not OS dependent.

You can easily set it through

```
[table setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Check your connections to nib file and delegate properly.

Comment: Thanks for the input.First of all, I have connected my outlet properly. I am able to retrieve all the data into my tableview using the same outlet so I dont think that outlet is an issue. Secondly, I should be able to set the background color from the XIB, once the property is shown in the inspector. I tried all the colors but the color does not change. What should I do?