# UITableView backgroundColor always gray on iPad, Solution for Monotouch

Tags: ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have the same issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688007/uitableview-backgroundcolor-always-gray-on-ipad) except that I am working in Monotouch, not Objective-C. I am also using Monotouch-Dialog rather than Interface Builder.

So, to summarize that question, on a *iPad* the background of a grouped UITableView is always grey whereas on an iPhone it shows the standard striped background. I am wanting to get the same striped background showing when the application runs on an *iPad*.

I have tried the following in the ViewDidLoad override method (based on the answer posted in the question that I linked), but it does not work:

```
public class SyncDialog : DialogViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        this.TableView.BackgroundView = new UIView();
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the background of the a *Monotouch.Dialog* *DialogViewController* on the *iPad* consistent with that shown on *iPhone*?

UPDATE:

I also tried changing the *BackgroundColor* of the tableview to *UIColor.Clear* as another answer tot the same question indicated. So I added:

this.TableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

But this also did not help. I also tried setting *this.TableView.BackgroundView* to *null* rather than instantiating another UIView object. But with both of these changes I just got a black background.

Answer (score 0):

The sample that you referenced also indicates that you need to set the TableView.BackgroundColor to UIColor.Clear

Comment: Hi Miguel. Thanks for the response. I actually did see the other answer to the question that I posted and tried setting the _BackgroundColor_ to _UIColor.Clear_. But that did not help. All I got was a black background then.