# iPad: cannot change UITableView background color

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Steps to reproduce:

1. in storyboard add new ViewController;
2. add table view
3. In Attributes inspector:

   - change style to grouped;
   - set prototype cells to 1;

   **- change table view background color to pink**

Thats it !! And you will see that color didn't change when you set it to pink. Why ? How to change background color ?

P.S. Its  works on iPhone

Comment: Okay, so the table is showing up properly but the only thing that's wrong is the background color isn't updating, correct?

Comment: yes, I cannot change its background color

Comment: Sorry, found my question duplicated here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2688007/602011