# SWRevealViewController does not load on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

[image: Side menu tableView does not load on iPad]

Side menu tableView of SWRevealViewController does not load on iPad,but loads perfectly on all iPhone devices?What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is Loading all right. Its that the iPad applies a white background to the cells.

Implement this method in your sidebar class :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

If you haven't added a subclass for your sidebar TableViewController, then create a class `SideBarTableViewController : UITableViewController`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27551291/3894781) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18878258/3894781) for more info.

#### Why is this happening?

Well some say its a bug, some others say its the intended bahaviour, but all I could find is this:

From the Apple DOCs ([UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html)):

> ... **In iOS 7, cells have a white background by default**; in earlier versions of iOS, cells inherit the background color of the enclosing table view. If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the ***tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:*** method of your table view delegate.

Comment: yeah..now it works .. but how do iPad simply applies a white background?

Comment: I am not sure whether thats a bug or if its the intended behaviour. but I'll let you know if I find anything.