# Calling super.tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath... with reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

First, I wanted to point out the reason I want to make a common call, when a reusable cell is dequeued in a base class, it's because of this line of code you will see again soon further in my question:

```
cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
```

This is a bug fix for iPad not respecting the UITableView.backgroundColor = myCustomColor and UITableViewCell.backgroundColor = clearColor I have set. iPad displays white instead, everything is fine in iPhone versions, you can see this bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551291/uitableview-backgroundcolor-always-white-on-ipad), I have to set the background color again each time the cell is dequeued that is the only solution that works for me. I am trying to do this once in my base class, and come up with a solution where I do not have to remember to call a func for every child class (might not be possible).

I have a couple custom `UITableViewControllers` classes, let's call them `ATableViewController` and `BTableViewController` they inherit from a base class called `UIBaseDashboardTableViewController` which inherits from `UITableViewController`.

I am generating dynamic Prototype Table cells and making use of the function below in `ATableViewController` and `BTableViewController`:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ATableViewCellId", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        //common setting to fix always white background in iPad bug
        cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
        return cell
    }
```

The TableViewCell Id `ACustomTableCellId` is unique or different for `ATableViewController` and `BTableViewController`. I have a common setting for all my `UITableViewControllers` that inherit from my base class, `UIBaseDashboardTableViewController`. You can see the backgroundColor line of code above is my common setting that will be the same in all child classes of `UIBaseDashboardTableViewController`. In each child class I first tried to do the following:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    super.tableView(tableView: tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    ...
}
```

But that is not going to work, I need the `ReusableCellIndentifer`.

My current solution, which really is just fine probably, is the following, in my child classes I have the following:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let data = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        let dequeuedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BTableViewCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let cell = dequeuedCell as! MyCustomTableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.model = data

        //call common settings for cells function in base class
        super.setDequeueReusableCellCommon(cell)

        return cell
    }
```

And then in my base class `UIBaseDashboardTableViewController` I implemented:

```
func setDequeueReusableCellCommon(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor
    }
```

The only downside to this is that I have to remember to call `super.v setDequeueReusableCellCommon` in all my child classes.

Any better suggestions on how solve this?

Comment: This seems overly complex to have the same background. Wouldn't you want to base subclass UITableViewCell as the shared inherited property is on that object not UITableView?

Comment: Its a bug fix for iPad displaying white background instead of the color I have set for the UITableView background color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing background color for cell, but made inheritance for tableViews. Use inheritance for tableViewCell, not the whole tableView. And in root class for tableViewCell setup `self.backgroundColor = self.contentView.backgroundColor` in `awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: That is kind of obvious lol, time for me to call it a night I think, thanks!