# UITableView is resetting its background color before view appears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm using probably a little bit exotic way of initialization of my UI components. I create them programmatically and among them is a UITableView instance, I set its background color immediately upon initialization, like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    let tableView = UITableView().tap {
         $0.backgroundColor = .black
         $0.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    ...
}
```

where `tap` is extension function:

```
func tap(_ block: (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
    block(self)
    return self
}
```

This worked very well in my previous project which was created in Xcode 8 and then migrated to Xcode 9 without breaking anything. But now I've created brand new project in Xcode 9 and copy-pasted above-mentioned extension to it, but seems like something went wrong. When my view controller appears on screen table has white background and default separator insets.

This seems to affect only some of the properties because others are working as they should have (e.g.  `$0.register(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)` registers required cell class and `$0.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false` hides scroll indicator).

Perhaps some of you, guys, could give me an idea what's the heart of the matter.

Here's [full code](https://gist.github.com/dkarbayev/80583019503e37c2e8cb83e601d84001), to reproduce the issue simply create a new project and replace ViewController.swift's content. As you can see, `table` has correct `rowHeight` (160) but resets its background color.

As for "before view appears" statement: I've printed table's background color in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` like this:

```
print(#function, table.backgroundColor.debugDescription)
```

– it changes its color only in the last debug print:

```
viewDidLoad() Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
viewWillAppear Optional(UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1)
viewDidAppear Optional(UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1)
```

Comment: I just tried it by copy pasting the code in the link you provided to playground - the color is set as expected. Perhaps there is some side-effect in the rest of your code?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I've tested in new blank project as well, it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: hm, it's interesting, when I run it on the device in normal project, it doesn't work either..

Comment: The strangest part is that if I change the background color in `loadView` before adding tableView as a subview and laying it out, it doesn't reset the color.

Comment: I mean, that's not strange but is as intended. The strange part is the topic itself.

Comment: I would just not create simple things like table view's "exotically" because complexity is what bugs live off of.

Comment: its because of the UIAppearance functions is it not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up moving the initialization to lazy var's function – turns out initializing UITableView during the initialization of it's view controller has some side effects.